# Scala Metaprogramming at Runtime

Tags: scala, metaprogramming

I'm building a tool that will receive unpredictable data structure, and I want to generate case class to accomplish the structure of the received data.
I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to generate case class at runtime? This structure will be know only at runtime.
It's something similar to what macro does, but in runtime.
I've found this project on the internet
[mars](http://www.google-melange.com/gsoc/proposal/public/google/gsoc2014/vova/5818821692620800)
Which is very close to what I want to do ,but I couldn't find if it was successful of not.

Another way of doing it is generate the code, compile and put the result in the classpath, like IScala is doing to use the code in an iterative way. But I don't think that this will scale.

Does anybody has already done something like runtime code generation?

This question was also posted in [scala-user](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-user/yGFIgyMFKqI) mailing list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** (as per the comments)

If all you want is throw-away code generated at runtime to be fed into to a library that cannot work with just lists and maps, and not code to be stored and used later, it would make sense to look for solutions to this problem for Java or JVM. That is, unless the library requires some Scala specific features not available to vanilla JVM bytecode (Scala adds some extras to the bytecode, which Java code doesn't need/have).

---

what is the benefit of generating statically typed code dynamically? as opposed to using a dynamic data structure.

I would not attempt that at all. Just use a structure such as nested lists and maps.

Comment: I need to create a case class because I need an instance of this data to be used in a library.

Comment: do you want to generate and store it? or just generate, use and throw away? if latter, how do you intend to use your generated classes from your static code? or the library uses reflection and can't operate on e.g. lists and maps?

Comment: It will be use and throw away, we won't store it. For now they probably use reflection and can't operate on list. This class is used to generate a schema which will be used for queries and computations.

Comment: In that case, how about you just search for: _"how to generate JVM bytecode/classes/code at runtime?"_ instead. That is, unless the library requires some Scala specific features not available to vanilla JVM bytecode (Scala adds some extras to the bytecode, which Java code doesn't need/have).

Comment: Well, that was something that I want to avoid, I was wondering if there wasn't a way to use macros at runtime, like the http://www.google-melange.com/gsoc/proposal/public/google/gsoc2014/vova/5818821692620800 project, which I now know it's active and I'll wait until it release.

Comment: Can you add this to your answer for me to accept it?

Comment: The point of macros is that they are run at compile time; you cannot do anything in a macro you can't otherwise do at runtime. They're just a means to execute code at compile time you would otherwise only be able to execute at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Runtime code generation is one of the purposes of [the Mars Project](http://www.google-melange.com/gsoc/proposal/public/google/gsoc2014/vova/5818821692620800). Mars is under development, at the moment there is no release version. Mars requires its own toolchain to expand macros at runtime and should use several features unique to scala.meta (http://scalameta.org/), for example, AST interpretation and AST persistence. Currently we are working on ASTs typechecking in scala-reflect, required for runtime macros expansion.